# jQuery Plugin Validate and Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate, validation

I am using the jQuery Plugin "Validate" to Validate a form I am using. It works and just needs a touch of styling with CSS for the error messages.

However, this is the issue. I am using Ajax to submit the form so when the user submits the form the form fades out and a nice success message shows. BUT if the user missed a required field the form fades out and they see an error message. They can click a button and see the form and where the error is. Now they fix the error and then they hit submit again. They now get form submission in progress and the form will not process. They must refresh the page to get the form to submit. It is a pain and is not a good process for the user.

Here is the question: How do I validate that the user has field in all of the required fields **BEFORE** they hit submit and avoid the issue mentioned above?

Thanks for any advice and help.

***EDIT*** Added Code:

AJAX and Validate Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function jqsub() {

var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
var $jform = $j('#contactform'); // form ID
var $jmessagebox = $j('#ajaxdiv'); // message box ID
var $jsuccessmessage = "<h3>We will be in contact soon. </h3>"; // success message in HTML format
var $jerrormessage = "<h3>Error - Please Try Again</h3><p class='light_button' id='errorbutton'>Return to Form </p><p>Please Note: You may have to refresh your page before you can submit the form again. We apologize for any inconvenience. </p><p>If the error continues please contact us at <a href='mailto:support@site.com'>Support@site.com</a></p>"; //error message in HTML format

$j.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $jform.attr('action'),
    data: $jform.serialize(), 
    success: function (msg) { 
                    if (msg.FormProcessV2Response.success) {
                    $jmessagebox.append($jsuccessmessage) 
                    $jmessagebox.fadeIn();
                    }
                    else {
                    $jmessagebox.append($jerrormessage) 
                    $jmessagebox.fadeIn();  
                    }    
            },
    error: function (msg) {
                        $jmessagebox.append($jerrormessage) 
                        $jmessagebox.fadeIn();
                },
   });
$jform.fadeOut("slow", function(){ //fade out of form after success
  $jmessagebox.fadeIn("slow");
});
$j("#errorbutton").live('click',function(){ //allows form to be faded in, in the event of an error
    $jmessagebox.fadeOut("slow", function(){
        $jform.fadeIn("slow");
    });
});

}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j('#contactform').validate();
});
</script>
```

FORM CODE:

```
<form action="/FormProcessv2.aspx?WebFormID=45926&amp;OID={module_oid}&amp;OTYPE={module_otype}&amp;EID={module_eid}&amp;CID={module_cid}&JSON=1" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkWholeForm33499(this)" method="post" name="catwebformform33499" id="contactform">
<fieldset>
<input name="FullName" type="text" class="required cat_textbox" id="FullName" value="{module_fullname}" maxlength="255" />
<label for="FullName">Full  Name<span>required</span></label>
<input name="EmailAddress" type="text" class="required email cat_textbox" id="EmailAddress" value="{module_emailaddress}" maxlength="255" /><label for="email">Email Address<span>required</span></label>
<input name="CellPhone" type="text" class="required cat_textbox" id="CellPhone" value="{module_cellphone}" maxlength="255" /><label for="cellphone">Cell Phone<span>required</span></label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<textarea onkeydown="if(this.value.length&gt;=1024)this.value=this.value.substring(0,1023);" class="required cat_listbox" rows="4" cols="10" id="CAT_Custom_254790" name="CAT_Custom_254790"></textarea></td>
<label for="message">Message<span>required</span></label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<label>Verification <span>required</span></label>
{module_captchav2}
</fieldset>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Send" tabindex="5" id="submit" name="submit" class="light_button_send" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CatalystScripts/ValidationFunctions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var submitcount33499 = 0;function checkWholeForm33499(theForm){var why = "";if (theForm.CaptchaV2) why += captchaIsInvalid(theForm, "Enter Word Verification in box below", "Please enter the correct Word Verification as seen in the image"); if(why != ""){alert(why);return false;}if(submitcount33499 == 0){submitcount33499++;jqsub();return false;}else{alert("Form submission is in progress.");return false;}}
//]]>
</script>
</form>
```

Comment: Added JS and Form code: The form code is messed up on the post not sure what I did wrong, can someone help correct the form code?  Thanks sorry for the form code being messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just have your fadeIn and fadeOut calls inside your $.ajax success function?

Something like

```
$j.ajax({
    .
    .
    .
    success: function (msg) { 
                if (msg.FormProcessV2Response.success) {
                    $jmessagebox.append($jsuccessmessage) 
                    $jmessagebox.fadeIn();
                    $jform.fadeOut("slow"
                                   , function(){ //fade out of form after success
                                       $jmessagebox.fadeIn("slow");
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $jmessagebox.append($jerrormessage) 
                    $jmessagebox.fadeIn();  
                }    
        },
        .
        .
        .
});
```

That way, he form only fades out if there were no errors.

As for your resubmission issue, the culprit is

```
if(submitcount33499 == 0){
   submitcount33499++;
   jqsub();
   return false;
}
else{
   alert("Form submission is in progress.");
   return false;
}
```

When the form is submitted the first time, `submitcount33499` gets ingremented (since it should have a value of 0 the first time around. The 2nd time around the test fails the test and goes into the else branch.

Why are you keeping track of if submission count anyway?

Comment: Good Idea, it still gave me form submission in progress when I tried to submit after I getting error of not filling in required field. Thoughts?

Comment: I use Business Catalyst and they generate the code for the forms and that is part of the code. I guess I should try removing it? I just do not want to break anything and JS is not my strong point. => Thanks for your help